# Django Admin - Create Custom List

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

I want to create a custom admin view. It should list specific objects from a model and *add attributes* to it.

More precisely, I have the tables **Student** and **Lecture**. Lecture has an attribute *enrolled_students*, which is a Many-to-Many relationship (Student can be enrolled in multiple lectures; a lecture can have many enrolled students). Students can gain points in a lecture, which determines their grade.

Therefore, I would like to provide an admin view, in which all students of a specific lecture are listed, along with their reached points and grade. The grade is computed lazily, as points are changing frequently.

How can I implement this? Is this possible using the built-in methods?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1**
I added the source code (simplified):

**Lecture**:

```py
class Lecture(UUIDModel, TimeFramedModel):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name="enrolled_lectures",
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
    )
    grading_scale = models.ForeignKey(
        GradingScale, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True
    )


    def get_score(self, user):
        """ Returns score of a particular user. """
        score = (
            user.submission_set
            .filter(exercise__lesson__lecture=self, score__isnull=False, exercise__rated=True)
            .values("exercise")
            .annotate(max_exercise_score=models.Max("score"))
            .aggregate(total_score=models.Sum("max_exercise_score"))["total_score"]
        )
        return score if score else 0
```

**Student (User model):**

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(_("full name"), max_length=130)
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["full_name"]

    objects = UserManager()
```

**GradingScale** contains the method *get_grade(score)*.  You can find the whole source code [here](https://github.com/rattletat/homework-checker/tree/main/server/apps).

Comment: Can you share the `Student` and `Lecture` models?

Comment: @AjayLingayat I added the source code.